# How to setInfoWindowAdapter for particular markers only

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to use the 'setInfoWindowAdapter' propery within my map view for a particular marker, but with 'Marker 2' there appears to be some unwanted space appearing underneath the title for some reason (Marker 2) (see attached screenshots). What can be done in order to prevent this from happening?

**FragmentCustomMapview.java**

```
public class FragmentCustomMapview extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public FragmentCustomMapview() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    SwitchCompat swt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custommapview, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_custommapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this); //this is important

        swt = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.switch_map_custommapview);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        swt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                initMap(isChecked);
            }
        });

        initMap(swt.isChecked());

        // Add markers and move the camera
        LatLng marker1 = new LatLng(51.510256, -0.135106);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(marker1)
                .title("Lorem ipsum dolor")
                .snippet("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
        );

        LatLng marker2 = new LatLng(51.509793, -0.134961);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(marker2)
                .title("Marker 2")
        );    


        mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                Context mContext = getActivity();

                LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                TextView title = new TextView(mContext);
                title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());
                title.setSingleLine(false);

                TextView snippet = new TextView(mContext);
                snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                snippet.setMultiline(false)

                info.addView(title);
                info.addView(snippet);

                return info;
            }
        });

        // Updates the location and zoom level of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.509932, -0.134720), 18);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    private void initMap(boolean isChecked){
        if (isChecked) {
            mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.string.style_json)));
        } else {
            mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**1st marker**

[image]

**2nd marker**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add your `TextView snippet` to your `LinearLayout info` if your `Marker` has no snippet:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    Context mContext = getActivity();

    LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView title = new TextView(mContext);
    title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
    title.setSingleLine(false);

    info.addView(title);

    if (marker.getSnippet() != null) {
        TextView snippet = new TextView(mContext);
        snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        snippet.setSingleLine(false);

        info.addView(snippet);
    }

    return info;
}
```